# autoclick hyperlink using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, hyperlink

I know there are a lot of answers around this but i do not seem to be able to find one to fit my purpose. I am submitting a form to a page and as long as all fields are inserted into the table it produces the below link. all this works fine. however i want to add javascript or something to auto click the link so it works as an auto redirect. Im trying this method as i have read you cannot post through header:location. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    echo "<a id='autolink' href='view_incident.php?inc_id=" . $inc_id . "'>" . $inc . "</a>";


    echo "
    <script>
    document.getElementById("autolink").click();
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: its `submit()` not `.click()` but why not just make the link a submit button?

Comment: your link is also NOT a POST request. its GET. 
and for a GET you CAN use header location in php.

Comment: @smith just changed to submit and it does not work.Im trying to get a great experience rather than direct to a blank page with just a submit button on to then be transferred.

Comment: @swissswiss i did not know that. Is that header:location URL ?INC_ID ect?

Comment: i assumed there was a form you were not showing us? i guess not

Comment: yes thats possible. but its more efficient to do everything in php directly.
i don't completely understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer you gave below was perfect thanks. I tried something similar but must have missed something out. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Location: view_incident.php?inc_id=' . $inc_id);
```

why not like this?